# Responsive Logo - Menu Overlaps Logo

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am using Gantry on a template for Joomla 2.5 The template was set to host a small image as a logo at the first point but i wanted it changed to a bigger one in ters of width.

So, now it doesn't work on ipad as it goes out of box and the menu appears on top of it.

I want the logo to resize as the page view becomes bigger but not to overlap the menu. Can you please help me out with that ?

The url is : `http://174.142.32.91/~thanos/example/`

Thanks in advance,

Nick

Comment: Can you show the relevant code please?

Comment: Yes, it is this one. 

/****************************  logo  ****************************/

.logo-block {
 padding: 0 15px;
 margin: 7px 10px;
}

#rt-logo {
 margin: -9px 0 0 0;
 width: 370px;
 height: 84px;
 display: block;
}

Comment: You need to narrow down your question, and not put a link to your site, make a jsFiddle. And dont try to put code in comments.

Comment: Sorry about that. I didn't understood the rules correctly.
This is not a live site though and will never be used. I just uplaoded it to post it over here.
jsFiddle won't work on this case because the css cde is extremely complicated (Less Css, Bootstrap etc.)

Comment: You should put your logo in a `<img>` tag in your markup instead of as a background image and change the fixed width you have set to `#rt-logo { width: 100%;}`

Comment: Use `max-width: 100%`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use fixed dimensions AND get the responsive, resizing qualities you are looking for.  Furthermore, you shouldn't use a background image if you want it resizing. To fix you code, it is simple.

Add the background image as a html image inside of your

```
<div class="rt-block logo-block">
    <a href="/~thanos/example/" id="rt-logo">
        <img src="http://174.142.32.91/~thanos/example/images/example.png" /> // This is your image
    </a>
</div>
```

Next, remove the following from your css:

```
#rt-logo{background:url("../images/logo/logo1.png") no-repeat;}
#rt-logo{margin:-9px 0 0 0;width:172px;height:84px;display:block;}
```

Comment: You have right, the background was the proble. I just disabled the logo from the template settings and added a new module in the same position the logo was, containing the logo on an <img> tag.

Answer (score 0):

That's because gantry uses background image for displaying logo.
You have three ways:

1. Do it the css way:
   You can use [CSS3 *backgrournd-size* property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) (which works in IE 9 or later) and some correction. You can put your css codes in gantry-custom.css file under templates/gantry/css folder (Create the file if it's not there) or you can edit the LESS files in templates/gantry/less folder.
2. Override the *logo feature* of gantry to img element in order to achieve this functionality. To override this feature copy the logo.php from *libraries/gantry/features* to *templates/gantry/features* if it does not already exist there and edit the *render* function.
3. Disable *logo feature* of gantry and use a module with the logo image as its content.

Comment: You have right, the background was the proble. I just disabled the logo from the template settings and added a new module in the same position the logo was, containing the logo on an <img> tag.

Comment: I added your idea as a solution to others seeing this question, and as an answer if you like!